# Discord bot only registers first one slash command

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to upgrade one of my bots to use the new slash commands featured in Discord.js v13. I have done some research and figured out how to register slash commands, and how to respond to them. I then spent some time amending my current command handler and came up with this:

```js
client.commands = new Map();
fs.readdir("./commands/", async (err, files) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    if (!client.application?.owner) await client.application?.fetch();
    let count = 0;
    let commands = [];
    for (let file of files) {   
        const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
        let commandData = { name: command.name };
        count += 1;
        const slashCommand = await client.guilds.cache.get("GUILD ID")?.commands.create(commandData);
    }
    console.log(`Registerd ${count} commands!`);
});
```

Here is also the code within my `interactionCreate` event and my two commands:

```js
module.exports = async (client, interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = await client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
    command.run(client, interaction);
}
```

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "ping",
    async run(client, interaction) {
        interaction.reply("Pong!");
    }
}
```

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "pong",
    async run(client, interaction) {
        interaction.reply("Ping!");
    }
}
```

All of this works almost perfectly, however my bot only seems to create the first slash command `ping`. The other command is added to the `client.commands` map fine, but when I try and run `/pong` nothing happens.

Comment: No errors? The `Registered 2 commands!` gets logged correctly?

Comment: Yes and yes. Unless I am accidentally catching an error somewhere, it is all syntactically correct.

Comment: I'd say add `console.log`s (and/or breakpoints) in a few places, e.g. see if that `interaction.commandName` is correct. Also, any reason you're using `await client.commands.get(...)`? Shouldn't be a Promise. The `command.run(...)` afterwards is, though.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. And `async/await` and Promises are rather new concepts for me so I'm still trying to figure out how to use them correctly. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: That's fine. An extra `await` isn't a big deal. If you `await` something with `.then` such as a Promise, it'll properly wait. If it doesn't, then it acts as if you didn't use `await` on it in the first place. The main thing with Promises is that you need to make you're either `await`'ing them or `.catch`'ing them. Otherwise you end up with some "uncaught promise rejection" errors, which (also) indicates bad code design, since you're "leaking" errors.

Comment: Ahh okay, that makes sense. Thank you for your help!